# Connecting to database using Windows Athentication

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, authentication, connection-string

I would like to use window authentication in my program to connect to my sql server. users already have certain permissions on the SQL server and I would like to leverage that in my program. The way I currently connect to the server is using this connection string.

```
Dim ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog = m2mdata02;User ID=ID;Password=Password;"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `Integrated Security=SSPI` and remove username and password from the connection string.

```
Dim ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=m2mdata02;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```